# Test static method that call another from same class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have a class:

```php
namespace Models;

use Contracts\PathContract;

class Path implements PathContract
{
    public static function getStorage(string $type): string
    {
        return storage_path(config('logs.storage_path', 'logs'))
            .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            .$type;
    }
    
    public static function directoryExists(string $type): bool
    {
        var_dump(Path::getStorage($type)); // output: .../logs/vendor/orchestra/testbench-core/laravel/storage/logs/myCustomType
        if (is_dir(self::getStorage($type))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I would like test `directoryExists` static method:

```php
public function testDirectoryExists(): void
{
    $path = Mockery::mock(Path::class)->makePartial();
    $path->shouldReceive('getStorage')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('/var/log');

    var_dump($path::getStorage('blah blah blah')); // output: /var/log

    $this->assertTrue($path::directoryExists('myCustomType'));
}
```

From `directoryExists` method, `getStorage` method doesn't return mock value but return real value. Any ideas ?

How can I test a static method that call another from same class ?

Comment: It's not possible to mock / change the implementation of a hard-wired (static) call. You should change to using Dependency-Injection, because this way you can swap in your mocked class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No no no. **You MUST mock dependencies**, not testing code.
Static function is bad design for testing.

If the functions weren't static, you could use `Filesystem` and mock them.

In this case, the best way is to `mock` the directory by using `temp`.

```
public function testDirectoryExists(): void
{
    //prepare
    $temp = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $logsPath = 'logs';
    $logsDir = $temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$logsPath;
    $type = 'someType';
    mkdir($logsDir);

    //mock
    $this->app->useStoragePath($temp);
    config()->set('logs.storage_path', $logsPath);

    //assert not created
    $this->assertFalse(Path::directoryExists($type));

    //assert created
    mkdir($logsDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$type);
    $this->assertTrue(Path::directoryExists($type));
}
```

### Updated

Or, **if you use Laravel**, you can use `File` facade:

```php
public static function directoryExists(string $type): bool
{
    return File::isDirectory(self::getStorage($type));
}
```

```php
public function testDirectoryExists(): void
{
    $type = 'myType';
    $expectedDir = '/logs/vendor/orchestra/testbench-core/laravel/storage/logs/'.$type;

    $mock = Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::class);
    $mock->shouldReceive('isDirectory')
        ->with($expectedDir)
        ->andReturn(true);

    $this->app->instance(\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::class, $mock);

    $this->assertTrue(Path::directoryExists($type));
}
```

Comment: Using File Facade works in a Laravel-Context, but the question was more generic I think.

Comment: He use storage_patch() - it,s laravel :) But you are right, updated

Comment: Thank you ! indeed, I use Laravel but it's great to take generic use case